# How to integrate project into existing solution on TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, continuous-integration

Basically, what I need to do is to include my projects into existing solutions on TFS.
How can this be done?

Comment: Can you be more precise about where you are having problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what in particular is the problem here, but the solution should be relatively straight forward:

- Add the project(s) to an existing solution (if that is what you want) from within Visual Studio.
- Add the folder(s) containing the new project(s) to TFS from your file system, and commit.

PS: You can test that this works by checking out a second copy of the branch you are working on somewhere other than where you have made your change, and try opening the updated Visual Studio Solution there, and verifying that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but try to follow these steps:

1. Map an existing solution in TFS to a local workspace
2. Open the solution in Visual Studio
3. Right-click on solution in Solution Explorer --> select Add --> select existing project
4. Navigate to the .csproj file that represents the project you want to add to the solution
5. Open up your pending changes window and observe all the files that have been modified
6. Select all these files and press Check-in

Comment: thanks, both answers were helpfull